# Javascript loop calculation

Tags: javascript, loops

Using the below script

```js
    
var lvl = 0;
var HappB = 5;
var DecoX = 5;
var DecoY = 5;

while (lvl < 5) {
  document.ofrm.UpgSD.value += Math.ceil((Math.exp((HappB + lvl) / ((DecoX * DecoY) * 1.8))) * 1 * 130000 * (Math.tanh((lvl + 1) / 20)) * (Math.tanh((lvl + 1) / 20)));
  lvl++;
}
```

```html
<form name="ofrm">
  <input type="text" name="UpgSD" size="50" tabindex="1">
</form>
```

The result is

> 363147633676050952513778

The expected output is

> 363 + 1476 + 3367 + 6050 + 9525 + 13778 = **34559**

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think `.value` is a `String` and not a number, you need to pass it to `parseInt()`

Comment: Despite its name, `xxx.xxx.value` is a *string*. I don't see where you (think) add a `+` (string!) anywhere.

Comment: `<input>` values are always strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated code. 
1. Your loop condition needs to be corrected. 
2. .value is string. You can set to a variable and then attach it.

```js
var lvl = 0;
var HappB = 5;
var DecoX = 5;
var DecoY = 5;
var number = 0;


while (lvl <= 5) {
  number += Math.ceil((Math.exp((HappB + lvl) / ((DecoX * DecoY) * 1.8))) * 1 * 130000 * (Math.tanh((lvl + 1) / 20)) * (Math.tanh((lvl + 1) / 20)));
  lvl++;
}
 document.ofrm.UpgSD.value = number;
```

```html
<form name="ofrm">
  <input type="text" name="UpgSD" size="50" tabindex="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `document.ofrm.UpgSD.value` is being cast into a string (rather than a number).

```
var lvl = 0;
var HappB = 5;
var DecoX = 5;
var DecoY = 5;
var initialValue = parseInt(document.ofrm.UpgSD.value);

while (lvl < 5) {
  initialValue += Math.ceil((Math.exp((HappB + lvl) / ((DecoX * DecoY) * 1.8))) * 1 * 130000 * (Math.tanh((lvl + 1) / 20)) * (Math.tanh((lvl + 1) / 20)));
  lvl++;
}

document.ofrm.UpgSD.value = initialValue;
```